# Mac Terminal - rename *.png.png to *.png

Tags: terminal, osx, rename, batch-jobs

I have a bunch of images that I'd like to rename as follows:

- `*.png.png --> *.png`
- `*.jpeg.jpg --> *.jpg`
- `*.JPEG --> *.jpg`

The only thing I've tried thus far is `mv *.png.png *.png`, but I knew that wouldn't work, but took a chance nevertheless.

Is there a simple (or maybe not) way to batch rename files with this pattern?

Comment: If you are seeking a command try `mmv`. It allows to specify wildcards; make sure you use quotes so that the shell does not expand those wildcards and `mmv` can act on those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something using `find` to rename `*.png.png -> *.png`:

```
find ./ -name '*.png.png' -type f \
        -exec sh -c 'mv {} ./$(basename -s .png.png {}).png' \;
```

It isn't really gerenic, so you have to customize it for the other file extensions.

Comment: Thanks! Let me give that a bash (no pun intended) and let you know

Comment: Works like a charm! Changed it for other extensions. Thank you, FloHimself

Comment: You could use parameter expansion thus avoiding using command substitution. This will strip the extra file extension off the file name  and rename the file `-exec bash -c 'file={}; mv "$file" "${file%.*}"' \;`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shell-only solution for the three cases you have in your question:

```
for f in *.png.png ; do mv -i "${f}" "${f%.png}" ; done

for f in *.jpeg.jpg ; do mv -i "${f}" "${f%.jpeg.jpg}.jpg" ; done

for f in *.JPEG ; do mv -i "${f}" "${f%.JPEG}.jpg" ; done
```

Type it in the directory where the files are to be renamed.

If you like to generalize this type of solutions in form of a replace suffix script you can do:

```
#!/bin/sh
from=${1:?} to=${2:?}
for f in *${from} ; do mv -i "${f}" "${f%${from}}${to}" ; done
```

and call that script with two parameters, the suffix to replace, and the new suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename`. Specially designed to work with multiple files.

Shorter. Cleaner.

*.png.png --> *.png

`% rename 's/.png.png$/.png/' *.png`

*.jpeg.jpg --> *.jpg

`% rename 's/.jpeg.jpg$/.png/' *.jpeg.jpg`

*.JPEG --> *.jpg

`% rename 's/.JPEG$/.jpg/' *.JPEG`

More comprehensive manual :

`% man rename`

Comment: Notice that if this is following the `sed` regexp syntax, you should escape the `.` as otherwise it would also match `imagepng.png` for example (with the first `.` matching the `e` as "any single character)